# GoDaddy Domain Name not keeping full URL path

Tags: url, dns

I have a domain name from godaddy (example... newdomain.com) and I am trying to mask the public IP address of my Django web application in my server. The settings for my newdomain.com in GoDaddy is "Forward with Masking."

The issue I am having is that every time I click the links in the web app the URL will always stay as newdomain.com. So for example in the webapp, I click a login button (which redirects to newdomain.com/login) the URL will always display as newdomain.com but the contents of newdomain.com/login will be displayed in the browser.

Please let me know if you have any clues on how to fix this, thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem; can you clarify what you mean by `the URL will always display as newdomain.com but the web page will actually display newdomain.com/login.`? What is displayed where exactly, and what is the `href` attribute of the "login" link?

Comment: Hi @Pekka웃, in the browser it will show newdomain.com/login but the URL displayed on the top will be newdomain.com.

Comment: What do you mean by "on the top"? In the page? In the browser?

Comment: Yes the URL of the browser will ALWAYS display newdomain.com but the CONTENTS of the page shows the correct URL (in this case newdomain.com/login). I want it to display newdomain.com/login but it instead displays only newdomain.com.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Then Godaddy's "Forward with masking" means they're using a Frameset. That's a quick and simple fix that kind of works, but doesn't allow for what you want. What other options do you see there? (What you want to do *may* be impossible with the options Godaddy gives you, because you'd need [proxying](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html)).

Comment: The other viable options (I think) I see are: "Forward Only", "DNS Records", and CNAME.

Comment: "Forward Only" won't help, that's just going to redirect. "DNS Records" is the cleanest way if you can set up the Django server to handle the domain name.

Comment: This is more appropriate for Webmasters than for StackOverflow: 
  This page there should answer your question: [Domain forwarding (GoDaddy) - Forward only / Forward with masking](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55050/domain-forwarding-godaddy-forward-only-forward-with-masking)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Webmasters.